# Memoized IO function?

Tags: haskell

just curious how to rewrite the following function to be called only once during program's lifetime ?

```
getHeader :: FilePath -> IO String
getHeader fn = readFile fn >>= return . take 13
```

Above function is called several times from various functions.
How to prevent reopening of the file if function gets called with the same parameter, ie. file name ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would encourage you to seek a more functional solution, for example by loading the headers you need up front and passing them around in some data structure like for example a `Map`. If explicitly passing it around is inconvenient, you can use a `Reader` or `State` monad transformer to handle that for you.

That said, you can accomplish this the way you wanted using by using `unsafePerformIO` to create a global mutable reference to hold your data structure.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

memo :: MVar (Map.Map FilePath String)
memo = unsafePerformIO (newMVar Map.empty)
{-# NOINLINE memo #-}

getHeader :: FilePath -> IO String
getHeader fn = modifyMVar memo $ \m -> do
  case Map.lookup fn m of
    Just header -> return (m, header)
    Nothing     -> do header <- take 13 `fmap` readFile fn
                      return (Map.insert fn header m, header)
```

I used an `MVar` here for thread safety. If you don't need that, you might be able to get away with using an `IORef` instead.

Also, note the `NOINLINE` pragma on `memo` to ensure that the reference is only created once. Without this, the compiler might inline it into `getHeader`, giving you a new reference each time.

Comment: Thank you. If I would like to avoid unsafePerformIO so 'memo' would return an IO action will this still work ? I guess it will be now called every time it has to be evaluated.

Comment: @DavidUnric: No, the memoization wouldn't work then, since you'd get a new empty `Map` every time, so you would load the text from the file every time. You could create the `MVar` in one place and then pass that around, but then you might as well pass the `Map` around directly.

Comment: hammar> Thx for the explanation. I did refactored the code so the header is now passed around from the first IO function just before it is used. Although I'm going to mark Your asnwer as it shows another approach I was not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing is to just call it once at the beginning of `main` and pass the resulting `String` around to all the other functions that need it:

```
main = do
    header <- getHeader
    bigOldThingOne header
    bigOldThingTwo header
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about this way but find it a bit uncomfortable, because header has to be passed to all chained functions even if there is no use of this parameter to them.

Comment: @DavidUnric: You should look into reader monads. They solve exactly that problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [monad-memo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo) package to wrap any monad into `MemoT` transformer. The memo table will be passed implicitly thoughout your monadic functions. Then use `startEvalMemoT` to convert memoized monad into ordinary `IO`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Control.Monad.Memo

getHeader :: FilePath -> IO String
getHeader fn = readFile fn >>= return . take 13

-- | 'memoized' version of getHeader
getHeaderm :: FilePath -> MemoT String String IO String
getHeaderm fn = memo (lift . getHeader) fn

-- | 'memoized' version of Prelude.print
printm a = memo (lift . print) a

-- | This will not print the last "Hello"
test = do
  printm "Hello"
  printm "World"
  printm "Hello"

main :: IO ()
main = startEvalMemoT test
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use unsafePerformIO to solve this.  The correct way to do exactly what you describe is to create an IORef that holds a Maybe, initially containing Nothing.  Then you create an IO function which checks the value, and performs the computation if it is Nothing and stores the result as a Just.  If it finds a Just it reuses the value.

All of this requires passing around the IORef reference, which is just as cumbersome as passing around the string itself, which is why everybody directly recommends just passing around the string itself, either explicitly or implicitly using the Reader monad.

There are incredibly few legitimate uses for unsafePerformIO and this is not one of them.  Don't go down that path, otherwise you'll find yourself fighting Haskell when it keeps doing unexpected things.  Every solution that uses unsafePerformIO as a "clever trick" always ends catastrophically (and that includes readFile).

Side note - you can simplify your getHeader function:

```
getHeader path = fmap (take 13) (readFile path)
```

Or

```
getHeader path = take 13 <$> readFile path
```

Comment: Pretty sure you'd need an `MVar` to get the right semantics for this.