# Memoizing IO Computations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, memoization

I have a function

```
f :: MonadIO m => a -> m b
```

which takes some input and returns an IO computation that will yield output.  I want to "memoize" `f` so that I only ever perform these computations once for each input.  For example, if

```
f :: String -> IO String
f s = putStrLn ("hello " ++ s) >> return s
```

then I want a function `memoize` such that

```
do
  mf <- memoize f
  s <- mf "world"
  t <- mf "world"
  return (s,t)
```

prints `"hello world"` exactly once and returns `("world", "world")`.  The program I'm writing is multi-threaded, so this property should hold even if different threads are all calling `mf`.

Below is the (terrible) solution I've come up with so far.  My question is whether and how it can be improved.

```
memoize :: (MonadIO m, Ord a) => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> m b)
memoize f = do
  cache <- liftIO $ newTVarIO Map.empty
  return $ \a -> do
              v <- liftIO $ atomically $ lookupInsert cache a
              b <- maybe (f a) return =<< liftIO (atomically $ takeTMVar v)
              liftIO $ atomically $ putTMVar v $ Just b
              return b
    where
      lookupInsert :: Ord a => TVar (Map a (TMVar (Maybe b))) -> a -> STM (TMVar (Maybe b))
      lookupInsert cache a = do
                         mv <- Map.lookup a <$> readTVar cache
                         case mv of
                           Just v -> return v
                           Nothing -> do
                                   v <- newTMVar Nothing
                                   modifyTVar cache (Map.insert a v)
                                   return v
```

There are a few things going on here:

1) `cache` has type `TVar (Map a (TMVar (Maybe b)))`.  It maps inputs to `TMVar`'s that contain either a computed value, or `Nothing` (which indicates that a value hasn't been computed yet).  The function `lookupInsert` inspects `cache`, and inserts a new `TMVar` initialized to `Nothing` if none is present already.

2) The returned action first obtains the `v :: TMVar (Maybe b)` associated to `a`, then takes it, and either performs the computation `f a` to obtain a result or returns the value stored in the `Maybe` if it's available.  This `take` and `put` pattern is so that two different threads don't both run the computation `f a` after seeing that it hasn't been run yet.

Comment: I think you want the values in the map to be either `TVar (Maybe a)` or `TMVar b` (which is equivalent to `TVar (Maybe b)` under the hood).  You have two layers of emptiness when it seems like you only need one.  Second, you should combine all of your `atomically` actions into a single transaction to avoid race conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to combine the `atomically` actions since we might have to do the computation `f a` in the middle.  The latter exists in the monad `m`, so it seems like the `take` and `put` must be lifted to `m`.

Comment: Looks a bit like you're in the wrong monad to me.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah, what I really want is to be able to lift `m` actions into `STM`.  I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @davidsd You're right, I missed the `f`, but you can still combine the first two `atomically` commands since there is no intervening `IO` action.

Comment: Would an additional type class constraint of `MonadMemo` be acceptable?  If so, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo may provide the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memoized IO function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454255/memoized-io-function)

Answer (score 1):

I thought what you wanted was impossible, but turns out it is.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458721/1798971

I still can't figure out why that works!